# Select IDs with different value in another column in a specific sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I must extract Ids that have a different value in a different column called flag. The values are either 0s or 1s. The flags have a specific date associated to them.

**Objective:**

My objective has two requirements:

1. Extract ids that have both 0 and 1 in flag column
2. And only those that have Flag 1 before 0 (using the date column)

**Current Query:**

My current query only extract those with 0 and 1. Not sure how to get those with 1 before 0

```
select id 
from table1 
where id IN ( select id from table1 group by id having count(distinct flag) >1)
```

**Fiddle Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ([id] varchar(13), [flag] int, [dates] DATE)


INSERT INTO table1
VALUES
    ('123', 1, '2019-01-01'),
    ('123', 1, '2019-01-02'),
    ('325', 0, '2019-01-01'),
    ('325', 1, '2019-01-02'),
    ('666', 1, '2019-01-02'),
    ('666', 0, '2019-01-01'),
    ('666', 1, '2019-01-02'),
    ('777', 1, '2019-01-01'),
    ('777', 0, '2019-01-02')
```

**Output:**

The only Id that would satisfy both conditions is 777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select id from table1 t 
where flag = 1
and exists (
  select 1 from table1 where id = t.id and flag = 0 and dates > t.dates
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a595ffced9a1633f9da865b8514ea567)

To get full rows:

```
select * from table1 where id in (
  select id from table1 t 
  where flag = 1
  and exists (
    select 1 from table1 where id = t.id and flag = 0 and dates > t.dates
  )
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3bf077f4918a262a5d994b715a162f29)
Or with a UNION:

```
select * from table1 t 
where flag = 1
and exists (
  select 1 from table1 where id = t.id and flag = 0 and dates > t.dates
)
union all
select * from table1 t 
where flag = 0
and exists (
  select 1 from table1 where id = t.id and flag = 1 and dates < t.dates
)
order by id, dates
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f74c33706c2db90ed4b3336f6ced51b2)
And one more:

```
select * from table1 t 
where exists (
  select 1 from table1 
  where id = t.id 
  and 1 - flag = abs(t.flag) 
  and (t.flag = 1 and dates > t.dates) or (t.flag = 0 and dates < t.dates)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d5537a22fb91aadfc9c2ba584097aa74)

Comment: Fantastic solution @forpas! kudos

Comment: @forpas very nice but how would i be able to show all the subsequent rows? say if i want to know many different occurences happens after 1

Comment: This query fetches only ids that satisfy the conditions in your question.

Comment: indeed, but how would i fetch all the other rows associated to that ID?

Comment: What other rows?

Comment: @forpas the row that follows with its columns 777 1 20190101 and 777 0 20190102

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having min(case when flag = 1 then date end) < max(case when flag = 0 then date end);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d95073d7081c638318530373809dca5) is the db<>fiddle.

Note that this works regardless of the number of rows for an id.

If you want the original rows, a simple method uses `in`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.id in (select id
                from table1
                group by id
                having min(case when flag = 1 then date end) < max(case when flag = 0 then date end)
               );
```

Comment: is there a way to get  all its corresponding rows to appear? 
777 1 2019-01-01 , 777 0 2019-01-02 ?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . Yes, but your question is explicitly "I must extract Ids" and that suggests that you just want ids.